# Indoor direction using wifi ESP8266 RSSI

Tags: wifi, esp8266

Good day.
Am trying to build a small device that is able to locate the direction of object indoor . not  location, only direction. I bought ESP8266E wifi chip and arduino 
[image: ESP8266 chip]. the ESP8266 is the receiver that must read the signal and specify the direction depending on the RSSI. first problem is that the ESP8266 is not directional and the access points around are not directional either . second problem is that the RSSI information takes long time to be read by the ESP8266 . each 3 seconds I can take on measurement. small measurement number make it difficult to analyze the results . I don't know if it is possible to build small directional antenna for the ESP8266E or not . and is the accuracy of the device would be reliable and maintain the device size small or accurate readings ?.[image: System structure]

Comment: I don't think using a WiFi signal is a good way to get directional info. It isn't intended for that.
And this isn't really a programming problem. It would probably be better for electronics.stackexchange.com or robotics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: thank you. it is not the right place. I think I will move the question to stack exchange

Answer (score 0):

Put 7cm straight  tin wire and test the direction, it works gets 7dB amplification max, hence u can find the source of transmitter according to direction of your straight tin wire